# How to override js functions in odoo 8?

Tags: javascript, python, xml, postgresql, odoo

want to customize IM chat button in odoo 8. i want to make it invisible for others except one group so i have inherited js file into my module. original file is im_chat.js file.

```
if(openerp.web && openerp.web.UserMenu) {
    openerp.web.UserMenu.include({
        do_update: function(){
            var self = this;
            var Users = new openerp.web.Model('res.users');
            Users.call('has_group', ['bms.group_custom_chats']).done(function(is_employee) {
                if (is_employee) {
                    self.update_promise.then(function() {
                        var im = new openerp.im_chat.InstantMessaging(self);
                        openerp.im_chat.single = im;
                        im.appendTo(openerp.client.$el);
                        var button = new openerp.im_chat.ImTopButton(this);
                        button.on("clicked", im, im.switch_display);
                        // button.appendTo(window.$('.oe_systray'));
                    });
                }
            });
            return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        },
    });
}
```

here i have inserted 'bms.group' instead of 'base.group_user'. the purpose of this function is it will hide chat button to users other than in that group. if i add that line into base file its working well, but the thing is its not working in this case.

`this is how is how I override the base js script`
I have saved im_chat.js file into my srcopenerp.py file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <template id="custom_unique_id" name="some name to template" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/bms/static/src/js/im_chat.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
```

This is python code for checking users of a group.

```
@tools.ormcache(skiparg=2)
def has_group(self, cr, uid, group_ext_id):
    """Checks whether user belongs to given group.

    :param str group_ext_id: external ID (XML ID) of the group.
       Must be provided in fully-qualified form (``module.ext_id``), as there
       is no implicit module to use..
    :return: True if the current user is a member of the group with the
       given external ID (XML ID), else False.
    """
    assert group_ext_id and '.' in group_ext_id, "External ID must be fully qualified"
    module, ext_id = group_ext_id.split('.')
    cr.execute("""SELECT 1 FROM res_groups_users_rel WHERE uid=%s AND gid IN
                    (SELECT res_id FROM ir_model_data WHERE module=%s AND name=%s)""",
               (uid, module, ext_id))
    return bool(cr.fetchone())
```

Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use template id as **im_chat.assets_backend** instead of **custom_unique_id**. Please add below code in your xml file and upgrade module, you will see the effect of your module.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="im_chat.assets_backend" name="im_chat assets"
            inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/bms/static/src/js/im_chat.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
```

Comment: It also stopping other group users to see chat button.. What to do now??